# Nodejs: downloading and transforming large data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js

I use Node JS. (Sails JS framework, but that's less important).

**Purpose**

Download a CSV file that includes data transformed from MongoDB.

That's the scenario of the server on a response to a large data download request

1. Read data from MongoDB.
2. Transform the data format (to CSV).
3. Send the data to response. (Download).

So, the user is expected to download this large data to their browser.

I'm not sure what would be the best way to handle such request.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow - there's no right way to answer this - it's very broad with many potential answers.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has built-in support for streaming and Node.js clients can provide a readable stream for the cursor. All HTTP response objects also provide a way to stream the response body through a series of writes or you can pipe to a socket when using WebSockets. Most of the work will be offloaded to the MongoDB server and Node.js was developed for exactly these kinds of requirements.

If you're going to use HTTP on the client side, you can use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and stream the response body into memory. Here is an [excellent article](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/) that shows how to efficiently process a response for large a CSV file:

```
const res = await fetch('/big-data.csv')
const csvStream = response.body
    .pipeThrough(new TextDecoder())
    .pipeThrough(new CSVDecoder())

for (;;) {
    const {row, done} = await csvStream.read()

    if (done) break
    drain(row)
}
```

Don't forget that both the server and client support encoded content, so make sure you compress the responses to further improve I/O.

Answer (score -1):

It is always a good idea to post some code of what you have tried so far.

First, you would have to retrieve the data from MongoDB using something like [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) or Waterline if you are using SailsJS

Secondly you can use a library like [csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) to convert the data to a csv file.

Once you have created the file you can return the file to the user using the sails response like so:

```
res.attachment('path/to/file.csv');
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer questions like these - there's simply no right answer. This is a wide-open question.